# Is there a difference between "Technology Management" and "Management of Technology"?

Tags: masters, degree, management

Is there a difference between "Technology Management" and "Management of Technology"?

In academia, we come across degrees like MSc in Technology Management, MSc in Management of Technology, MBA in Technology Management etc. Have they given the names Technology Management/Management of Technology because of some difference, or are both the same, similar to how "Department of Chemistry" and "Chemistry Department" both mean the same?

Answer (score 2):

For this you probably need to look at the individual curriculum to see what is emphasized and what is assumed. Such a program might be considered a STEM program focused on the technology or a management program focused largely on people. They could be quite different or the same, depending.

Further exploration is needed.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Buffy then that means the program designer can design as they need and give either the name, according to their requirement I guess